# Wiring a membrane potentiometer to give two outputs

Tags: voltage-divider, potentiometer, passive-components

I'm using a [softpot](http://www.spectrasymbol.com/potentiometer/softpot/softpot-diagrams-and-schematics) membrane potentiometer in a project and I have found that pressing two fingers on the strip gives strange results. I was expecting it to short to the lower resistance value but in reality it gives some resistance in between.

In researching this, I found someone who managed to wire it acting as two voltage dividers giving both finger positions simultaneously - the video to this can be found here: https://vimeo.com/38404771

Could anyone explain what's happening in these two scenarios?

Answer (score 1):

With two fingers you get two connections from the "wiper" to the resistor so the resistances measured from the  wiper to each end of the resistor do not add up to the full resistance of the resistor.

By measuring the resistance from the wiper to each end of the resistor the position of two fingers can be measured.

Answer (score 1):

Measure the resistance from each end to the wiper bar. If only one point is touched then the resistance from each end to the wiper sums to the end-to-end resistance of the pot.  If the total resistance is < the pot, then two (or more) points are being touched, and a simple resistance measurement from each end to the wiper will indicate the "highest" and "lowest" point.

This method is effective only for 2 or fewer points. If there are more than 2 points, then only the two "outer" points can be determined. Any points inbetwen are invisible by this simple method.  It would take a more sophisticated method with something like matrix scanning to indicate more than 2 points.

Comment: Thanks for your help
Doesn't one pin have to be grounded? What's the best method for measuring the resistance from both ends with a microcontroller? I tried wiring the wiper to +3.3v and the other two to analog inputs but this seems to read high no matter the position.

Comment: I left the description of "measure the resistance" generic because exactly HOW you do that depends on several other factors which seem outside the scope of this question. I would bet that there are dozens of questions/answers how to measure resistance with a microcontroller.  It may involve connecting something to ground, or it may involve connecting something to the power bus, but that seems like a different question.

Comment: @dnv typically the wiper would be the common node (power or ground) as it is common to both measurements, but note that when the pot is not touched, both measuremnt nodes are connected to each other by the full resistance and the resistance to common from either is "infinity",